# $addField by regex condition with Mongo < 4.2

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB collection with the following objects:

```
{
name: "a",
email: "aaa@bestemail.com"
},
{
name: "b",
email: "bbb@bestemail123.com"
},
{
name: "c",
email: "ccc@diffemail.com"
}
```

I want to add to each document a field of true/false if the email address matches the /bestemail/ regex expression.

Meaning, for the current collection I would get:

```
{
name: "a",
email: "aaa@bestemail.com",
matching: true
},
{
name: "b",
email: "bbb@bestemail123.com",
matching: true
},
{
name: "c",
email: "ccc@diffemail.com",
matching: false
}
```

The main issue is that I have to work with **mongo version 4.0.12** and so I cannot use $regexMatch (available from mongo 4.2)

I have tried using:

```
$addFields: {"matching": {$cond: [{$in: ["$email", [/bestemail/]]}, true, false]}}
```

but I get `matching: false` for all documents.

Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hesitate to respond since I don't have access to a MongoDB server with version 4.0.12, but perhaps this will work. [I did look at the [archived docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/).]

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "matching": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$gt": [
              { "$indexOfCP": [ "$email", "bestemail" ] },
              0
            ]
          },
          true,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on the wrong server version at [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ehiEgAG64qZ).

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "email": "aaa@bestemail.com",
    "matching": true,
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "email": "bbb@bestemail123.com",
    "matching": true,
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "email": "ccc@diffemail.com",
    "matching": false,
    "name": "c"
  }
]
```